# How can i call the parameterized constructor for all objects in my dynamic array of objects on allocation in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor, dynamic-arrays

When i define dynamic array of objects, i want to choose one parameterized constructor for all objects in my array. without having to write for each object the chosen constructor like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class foo {
public:
    foo ()
    { 
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
    }


    foo (int x)
    {
        cout << "parameterized constructor " << endl;
    }

    ~foo ()
    {
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
    }
};


int main (void)
{
    int size = 3, parameter = 10;
    foo *array;
    array = new foo [size] { foo(parameter), foo(parameter), foo(parameter) };

    cout << endl;

    delete [] array;
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
parameterized constructor 
parameterized constructor 
parameterized constructor 

destructor
destructor
destructor
```

So, as you can see from the above code, I can choose parameterized constructor for each object in my array `array = new foo [size] { foo(parameter), foo(parameter), foo(parameter) };`.
However, if user inputs the `size`. same trick won't work

When I searched for solution, I found that I can do it with copy constructor like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class foo {
public:
    foo ()
    { 
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
    }


    foo (int x)
    {
        cout << "parameterized constructor " << endl;
    }

    ~foo ()
    {
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
    }
};


int main (void)
{
    int size = 3, parameter = 10;
    foo *array;
    array = new foo [size];

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = foo(parameter);

    cout << endl;
    
    delete [] array;
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
default constructor
default constructor
default constructor

parameterized constructor 
destructor
parameterized constructor 
destructor
parameterized constructor 
destructor

destructor
destructor
destructor
```

However, destructors are called for each object, and i don't want this
i just want to do it while allocating for the first time

Thanks in advance, and I hope that there's a solution.

Comment: A solution is the same as `std::vector` uses. First, allocate storage and then initialize objects in it. With the array form of `new` expression, only value-/default-initialization can be applied: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to this problem would be to use `std::vector` which handles all those problems internally, e.g.:

```
#include <vector>
// skipping class declaration for brevity
int main (void)
{
    int size = 3, parameter = 10;
    std::vector<foo> array;
    array.reserve(size);

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array.emplace_back(parameter);

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, if for some reason you want/need to do this by hand then you should be allocating a "raw buffer" and construct objects inside that buffer with placement `new` - this will however also require you to manually call the destructors

One possible example, doing everything "manually" could look like this

```
int main (void)
{
    int size = 3, parameter = 10;
    foo *array = reinterpret_cast<foo*>(new char[size * sizeof(foo)]);

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        new (&array[i]) foo(parameter);

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i].~foo();

    delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>(array);
    return 0;
}
```

An arguably cleaner solution is to use `std::allocator` and `std::allocator_traits` - this would look like this

```
#include <memory>
// skipping class declaration
int main (void)
{
    std::allocator<foo> alloc;
    using alloc_t = std::allocator_traits<decltype(alloc)>;
    int size = 3, parameter = 10;
    foo *array;
    array = alloc_t::allocate(alloc, size);

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        alloc_t::construct(alloc, &array[i], parameter);

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        alloc_t::destroy(alloc, &array[i]);
    
    alloc_t::deallocate(alloc, array, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I would use a `for` loop :

```
array = new foo [size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   array[i] = foo(parameter);
}
```

I don't see a simpler way to do it. And with this method, your `size` can be parametrized easily.

For your "destructor issue", use pointer on foo :

```
array = new *foo[size];
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   array[i] = new foo(parameter);
}
```

But do not forget to delete each `foo` instance when needed :

```
for(int i = 0; i < size i++) {
   delete array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

Comment: op is already using a loop. I dont see how this is different from OPs code, other than the out-of-bounds error, that isnt present in OPs code. This code invokes undefined behaviour

Comment: "For your "destructor issue", use pointer on foo" ?!? why add more pointers? And you repeated the out-of-bounds several times more

Comment: The use of pointers is to avoid several allocations and destructions. Sorry for the out-of-bounds, I edited the answer to fix it X/.

Comment: *"The use of pointers is to avoid several allocations and destructions"* - but that is exactly what you are doing - you have a lot more allocations (and deallcations) than a regular array.

Comment: With regular array, the allocation are made in stack, but constructor and destructor are called 2 times : Once when allocating the array, and once when allocating each element in the loop. From what I have understood, we are trying to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: @Irog_Nos your solution also helpful i thank you,  but edit your main to work
```c++
int main (void)
{
    int size = 3, parameter = 10;
    foo **array;
    array = new foo *[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = new foo(parameter);
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        delete array[i];
    return 0;
}
```